# Active Directory Domains and Trusts wont start

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I just installed Active Directory on Windows Server 2008, but when I tried to open  Administrative Tools => Active Directory Users and Computers, it shows me this error meesage :

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is this the only DC? What is this DC using for DNS?

Answer (score 2):

You fix your connectivity to your domain's PDC Emulator. You can locate it by running `netdom query fsmo`. Once you know which server has the PDC Emulator role, you can check its health using `dcdiag /v`.